# 'ivreg' code (from AER package) works on weaker PC but not on stronger PC

Tags: r, performance, error-handling, compiler-errors

I try to run a 'ivreg' command in R in my desktop PC. However, when I run this code, it does not response permanently which I usually expect the results to come out in a second.

I try this same 'ivreg' command in my other laptop PC (which is much less compatible than my desktop PC) then the result comes out in a second.

I was using the exactly same code sheet and data but simply on a different computer, but one works (laptop PC with much weaker performance) and the other one (desktpo PC with much stronger performance) does not.

Strangely, all other codes work normally on both PCs but not only this code. Both PCs have this 'ivreg' related package (AER) installed properly.

May I get help on this please?

Comment: Have you tried updating the package on your desktop PC? or uninstall AER package to install it again? I know this is too basic, but sometimes big problems has humble solutions.

Comment: @ArielSC: Yes. My tried reinstalling my entire Windows and newly downloaded the R and packages again. But still do not work.

Comment: Can you get the sessionInfo() from both the systems?